# How to make Pandas Data Frame column data into array value and listed in new column

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When ever cve column null (NaN or NA) condition need to check @href column data availability , if data in @href then need to make @href and @cvss_score in array list same like **cve**  column data format **[{'@href': 'https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE','@cvss_score':'10'}]** and i want those data into new column. image-b is exact requirement.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'cve': [{'@href': 'https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE','@cvss_score':'10'}],'@href': '','@cvss_score': ''},
        {'cve': '','@href': 'https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE','@cvss_score': '10'},
        {'cve': '','@href': 'https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE','@cvss_score': '10'},
        {'cve': [{'@href': 'https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE','@cvss_score':'10'}],'@href': '','@cvss_score': ''}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

[image]

Image - B (required output)
[image]

Comment: What part of the code are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option :

```
df["ocdata"] = (df["cve"].replace("", None)
                  .fillna(pd.Series([[{"@href": h, "@cvss_score": c}]
                                     for (h,c) in zip(df["@href"], df["@cvss_score"])]))
)
```

Output :

```
print(df["ocdata"])

0    [{'@href': 'https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE', '@cvss_score': '10'}]
1    [{'@href': 'https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE', '@cvss_score': '10'}]
2    [{'@href': 'https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE', '@cvss_score': '10'}]
3    [{'@href': 'https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE', '@cvss_score': '10'}]
Name: ocdata, dtype: object
```